# How to change colours identified by the camera in Python

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

This program is used to identify red and blue colours from the camera.

Does anyone know how I can change the program to identify green colours instead of blue colours?

Thanks in advance!

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

red_lower = np.array([-10, 100, 100])
red_upper = np.array([10, 255, 255])
blue_lower = np.array([100, 43, 46])
blue_upper = np.array([124, 255, 255])
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

cap.set(3, 320)
cap.set(4, 240)
def ChestRed():
   hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
   mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, red_lower, red_upper)
   mask = cv2.erode(mask, None, iterations=2)
   mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (3, 3), 0)
   return mask
def ChestBule():
   ret, frame = cap.read()
   frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (5, 5), 0)
   hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
   mask = cv2.inRange(hsv, blue_lower, blue_upper)
   mask = cv2.GaussianBlur(mask, (3, 3), 0)
   cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
   if 25 < len(cnts) < 29:
       print("Blue!")
while 1:
   ret, frame = cap.read()
   frame = cv2.GaussianBlur(frame, (5, 5), 0)
   hsv = cv2.cvtColor(frame,cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
   mask = ChestRed()
   ChestBule()
   res = cv2.bitwise_and(frame,frame,mask=mask)
   cnts = cv2.findContours(mask.copy(), cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)[-2]
   if 20<len(cnts)<30:
       print("Red!")

   cv2.imshow("mask", mask)
   cv2.imshow("res", res)
   if cv2.waitKey(5) == ord('q'):
       break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to know how can you change the program to identify green colors instead of blue colors.
To do this just *change the blue_lower and blue_upper to respective HSV values to the shade of green you want to consider*.

***For a light shade of green use lower values as [50, 242, 220] and upper values as [80, 255, 255]***

It would we better if in this you use *np.array([x,y,z],dtype='uint8')* where x,y,z are the HSV values depending upon the color you want to mask

Comment: Thanks alot! You were a great help